# cant figure out what to write for the last string of code for function

Tags: c++

Hi guys this is what I have so far for my function and the question is asking me to Write a function `findpattern()` which will receive three integers representing the three bowling scores.  The function will determine the pattern followed by these scores, printing one of the following **six cases** (make sure you have these six cases):

```
  stayed the same –- all three scores were the same 

  increasing –- the scores are going steadily upward

  decreasing –- the scores are going steadily downward

  up and down –- the scores first went up, then went down

  down and up –- the scores first went down, then went up

  two the same –- two consecutive scores were the same, and the
 other one (first or third) was either higher or lower
```

This is what I have so far I can't figure out the last part any help will be appreciated

```
void findpattern(int score1, int score2, int score3)
{
   if (score1 == score2 && score1 == score3 && score2 == score3 )
   {
      cout << "all three scores were the same" << endl;
   } else if (score1 < score2 && score2 < score3) {
      cout << "the scores are going steadily upward" << endl;
   } else if (score1 > score2 && score2 > score3) {
      cout<<"the scores are going steadily downward"<<endl;
   } else if(score1 < score2 && score2 > score3) {
      cout << "the scores first went up, then went down" << endl;
   } else if (score1 > score2 && score2 < score3) {
      cout<<"the scores first went down, then went up"<<endl;
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps a space here and there would make it readable

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please use punctuation and capitalize the first letter of each sentence and the word i as it is you are saving yourself a very small amount of effort and making your question much more difficult to read

Comment: Apologizes beta will take this into consideration next time I post

Comment: Take it into consideration _this_ time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if ( ( ( score1 == score2 ) && score2 != score3 ) || ( ( score2 == score3 ) && ( score2 != score1 ) ) )
    cout << "two scores are equal" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks GraphicsMuncher

Comment: @john315 Please read the FAQ on how to ask good questions and how to properly use comments. If this answer solved your problem you can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
else if((score1==score2 || score2==score3) && ( (score1 > score3) || (score1 < score3)))
    cout<<"two the same";
```

Comment: Your method and Graphics method worked out fine thank you Sakib